# Where is this "overflow menu button" in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio

According to a tip [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-studio-tip-multiple), one can simultaneously view a layout in Android in various screen sizes and orientations. It says, "*Click on the overflow menu button > Preview All Screen Sizes. You can switch between landscape/portrait orientations too.*"

"Whey cool!" I thought, while serendipitously sitting on my tuffet.

But when I brought up Droidio (Android Studio), and a layout/*.xml file in Design mode, I sought in vain for any trace of "Preview All Screen Sizes". I then realized that I had misread the statement -- I had at first translated "overflow menu button" in my mind as the context menu. So...what is the "overflow menu button" and where is it?

Here's what I see:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click where it says 'Nexus 4' - at the bottom of the list of devices is the *Preview All Screen Sizes* option.